# How do I abstract my VBA code to handle n x n matrix smoothly?

Tags: excel, vba

Quick Background: I'm a team captain of a relay race whereby runners have put preferences as to what legs they are willing to run. For decades the captains have manually figured out where to put people, I want to automate it. There are Y number of runners (20 or more) for exactly 20 legs.

Current Situation: VERY crude code will find all combinations up to 3 legs of the race but it's clear I need to abstract and probably use arrays to do this. My code skills are rough (self-taught), trying to find assistance to expand below code to n x n instead of currently n x 3.

```
Sub B2VMacro()

   Debug.Print
   countRunners
   Debug.Print ("Here are the available leg assignments: ")
   
   For i = 2 To countRunners
      cellValue = Cells(i, 2).Value
      runnerNameLeg1 = Cells(i, 1).Value
      If cellValue = "X" Then
         For j = 1 To countRunners
            cellValue2 = Cells(j, 3).Value
            runnerNameLeg2 = Cells(j, 1).Value
            If cellValue2 = "X" Then
               If runnerNameLeg1 <> runnerNameLeg2 Then
                  For k = 1 To countRunners
                     CellValue3 = Cells(k, 4).Value
                     runnerNameLeg3 = Cells(k, 1).Value
                     If CellValue3 = "X" Then
                        If runnerNameLeg1 <> runnerNameLeg2 And runnerNameLeg2 <> runnerNameLeg3 And runnerNameLeg1 <> runnerNameLeg3 Then
                           Debug.Print (runnerNameLeg1 & " , " & runnerNameLeg2 & " , " & runnerNameLeg3)
                        End If
                     End If
                  Next k
               End If
            End If
         Next j
      End If
   Next i
   
End Sub

Function countRunners() As Integer

   countRunners = Worksheets("Template").Range("A:A").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count

End Function
```

Code works for n x 3 but it's going to become unmanageable expanding this to even 5 x n. Need to figure out how to abstract the code.

[image]

Expected Output (comma delineates leg of race):

Runner 1, Runner 2, Runner 4

Runner 1, Runner 3, Runner 4

Runner 2, Runner 3, Runner 4

Runner 3, Runner 1, Runner 4

Runner 3, Runner 2, Runner 4

Only Runner 4 agreed to run leg 3, Runner 2 did not agree to run leg 1, Runner 1 & 3 agreed to run legs 1 and 2 but not 3.

So I'd want every combination to cover all legs given the runner's preferences (X means they are willing to run that leg of the relay race). The full sheet has 20 legs and N runners (currently 20 but some years would be more like 30-40).

Comment: Why don't you describe the inputs to your code? what is in Column A, row 1, 2, etc.. where are the RunnerNames, etc..

Comment: ... adding screenshots of the source worksheet and the expected result would do wonders. You can [edit your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71641489/edit) at any time.

Comment: Please don't _only_ add a screen shot of your data.  Add it as text, so we can copy paste.   Add a screen shot as well, if you think it adds useful additional information

Comment: Even better - link to stripped down document. Unfortunately my work's security settings prevent me from saving it as a macro-enabled document so you'll have to copy/paste the above into VBA to run it. The X demarcates that a runner agreed that they could run that particular leg. [Google Drive] (https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RsBKxHuUjy1cvm0emzNDexBS1r6aokMp/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=114741461989471917798&rtpof=true&sd=true)

Comment: https://www.got-it.ai/solutions/excel-chat/excel-tutorial/possible-combinations/how-to-make-excel-list-all-possible-combinations

Comment: Don't use arrays.  Use dictionaries and array lists as the '.exists' and '.contains' methods respectively make it much easier to search your data.  You should also be aware that if you don't have a well defined manual method for how you allocate runners you will be making your life harder by trying to develop a set of rules for allocation and code and the code at the same time.  SO my advice is that if the allocation algorithm doesn't exist the developing code is a pointless exercise.

Comment: In your case, because at first instance you want to know how many combinations of athletes can do each leg, you want to calculate "variations without repetition" https://www.mathreference.org/index/page/id/52/lg/en#:~:text=Variation%20is%20a%20way%20of,of%20items%20is%20not%20allowed.&text=Vkn%3Dn!  As you can see the process is pretty complex. Think about it. As example, just 5 legs and 3 athletes implies 60 different possible combinations...

Comment: If you assume that a given runner will only run a single leg, and you have 40 runners who might each run any of the 20 legs, you will have an unmanageably high number of possible combinations (3.35*10^29)

Comment: I'm not convinced it's out of realm of possibility. Many of the runners self select out of the hardest legs. It's actually 2 teams of 20 not one team of 40. So assume 25 are strong enough to be on the competitive team - we know up front that there are about 5-8 strong enough for the hardest legs. This starts to dramatically reduce combinations.

Comment: I think you might have the opposite problem to the one of having too many combinations - in the Google doc there seem to be four legs that are only covered by the three strongest runners - not sure how that is going to pan out if each runner only does one leg.

Comment: I finally ran the program on your 20 legs / 20 runners data. Result: 16725330 reps and 1639848 possible ways of allocating runners - it took about ten minutes to run. I had to add a couple of extra runners to make it cover all legs.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a draft of a possible approach. The idea is to work through the legs from first to last, allocating the first available runner to each leg in turn. To get another set of allocations, backtrack from the last leg until a leg is found where an alternate runner can be allocated, then work forward from there as before.

```
Option Explicit
Option Base 1


Sub Runners()

    Dim Allocated() As Boolean
    Dim Legs() As Integer
    Dim arr() As Variant
    Dim col As Integer, row As Integer
    Dim tempRow As Integer, colFound As Integer, rept As Integer
    Dim lastRow As Integer, lastCol As Integer
    Dim nRunners As Integer, nLegs As Integer
    Dim outString As String
    
    lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row
    lastCol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    
    nRunners = lastRow - 1
    nLegs = lastCol - 1
    
    ReDim Allocated(nRunners)
    ReDim Legs(nLegs)
    
    arr = Range(Cells(2, 2), Cells(lastRow, lastCol))
    
    'Find initial allocation
    
    Call forwardSearch(1, nLegs, 1, nRunners, arr, Allocated, Legs)
    

    Call output(Legs, nLegs)
    
    ' Try again
    For rept = 1 To 10
    
        Call backTrack(nLegs, 1, nRunners, colFound, arr, Allocated, Legs)
        
        If colFound = 0 Then Exit Sub
              
        'Re-start search
        
        Call forwardSearch(colFound + 1, nLegs, 1, nRunners, arr, Allocated, Legs)
        

        Call output(Legs, nLegs)
    
    Next rept

End Sub

Sub forwardSearch(startCol As Integer, endCol As Integer, startRow As Integer, endRow As Integer, ByRef arr(), ByRef Allocated() As Boolean, ByRef Legs() As Integer)
    Dim col As Integer, row As Integer
    For col = startCol To endCol
        For row = startRow To endRow
            If Not Allocated(row) And arr(row, col) = "X" Then
                Allocated(row) = True
                Legs(col) = row
                Exit For
            End If
        Next row
    Next col
End Sub

Sub backTrack(startCol As Integer, endCol As Integer, endRow As Integer, ByRef colFound As Integer, ByRef arr(), ByRef Allocated() As Boolean, ByRef Legs() As Integer)
    Dim col As Integer, row As Integer, tempRow As Integer
    
    colFound = 0
    
    For col = startCol To endCol Step -1
    
        tempRow = Legs(col)
        
        For row = Legs(col) + 1 To endRow
        
            If Not Allocated(row) And arr(row, col) = "X" Then
            
                ' De-allocate existing runner
                Allocated(tempRow) = False
                
                'Allocate new runner
                Allocated(row) = True
                
                'Save new runner
            
                Legs(col) = row
            
                colFound = col
                Exit Sub
            End If
        
        Next row
        
        'Simply de-allocate current runner
        
        Allocated(tempRow) = False
    
    Next col

End Sub

Sub output(Legs() As Integer, nLegs As Integer)
    Dim col As Integer
    Dim outString As String
    outString = "Runner" & Legs(1)
    For col = 2 To nLegs
        outString = outString & ", Runner" & Legs(col)
    Next col
    Debug.Print outString
End Sub
```

*Output for test data*

```
Runner1, Runner2, Runner4
Runner1, Runner3, Runner4
Runner3, Runner1, Runner4
Runner3, Runner2, Runner4
```

*To do*

In the real data, any particular attempt (or all attempts) at allocating runners to legs may not get all the way to the final leg. Need to adjust program to take this into account. Also use runners' actual names. If the program were ever used on a large scale, change Integer to Long.